# Cannot run API remotely (API on Azure)

Tags: azure

I got an API published to Azure (no authorities needed to reach this api). The API contains a POST method which accepts a byte[]. When running the API locally (I am doing this through unity with the correct adress) it works as expected, but I get an Internal error 500 when running against the API with the remote adress. I say with confidence that the adress is not wrong, but something is though I can't figure out what.

The remote adress:
`https://XXX.azurewebsites.net/api/{controller}/{action}`

I don't really know what other information can help, so if some information is missing tell me and I'll update the answer.

Comment: you should turn on the error logging, and check what you can see there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs

Answer (score 0):

According to the remote address in your description, I think you were trying to call the REST API of Azure Web Apps or Azure Function Apps, such as the Kudu wiki page [`REST API`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API) said.

If so, it requires the request header must includes the credentials information. For that, you can refer to the other Kudu wiki page [`Deployment credentials`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials) to know it.

The basic auth in the calling request header is as below.

```
 Authorization: Basic <BASE64-Encode("deployment-username":"password")>
```

You can get the values of `deployment-username` & `password` on Azure portal as the figure below.

[image]

Comment: I am unsure if it's a REST or not, but my url does not have the `.scm` part in it? I also am not admin to the api, so I don't really know, but hopefully I'll get an answer soon!